# Getting ???? mark as response from php instead of getting Tamil text string.

Tags: php, android, web-services, android-studio

I'm having Tamil text in table and while i using PHP to retrieve data i'm getting ??? as response.

Following is my PHP code.

```
    <?php 
header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
include('connection.php');

$query = "SELECT * FROM DevotionalCollection";
$fetch=mysqli_query($con, $query ) or die(mysqli_error($con));

if (mysqli_num_rows($fetch) > 0) {
    $response["data"] = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch)) {

        $data = array();
        $data["playlistname"] = $row["playlistname"];
        $data["playlistid"] = $row["playlistid"];
        $data["channelname"] = $row["channelname"];
        $data["imageURL"] = $row["imageURL"];

        //$response["data"] = array();
        array_push($response["data"], $data);

    }
    header('Content-type: text/json');
    $response["success"] = TRUE;
    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}else {
    // no products found
    $response["success"] = FALSE;
    $response["message"] = "No data found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}

?>
```

And i getting response as

```
    {
  "data": [
    {
      "playlistname": "?????",
      "playlistid": "PLfLdj4WW-kHU4f4CGm2F9vG--ggvcy7PD",
      "channelname": "Lalitha Lalli",
      "imageURL": ""
    },
    {
      "playlistname": "Colour kolam. ???? ????????. Colour muggulu. Rangoli designs",
      "playlistid": "PLBYk4p11EVuoay-_RpW1x4f6N2eaE6rOO",
      "channelname": "TD Kolam",
      "imageURL": ""
    },
    {
      "playlistname": "Easy Rangoli. ????????. Muggulu",
      "playlistid": "PLBYk4p11EVuqkpL3gwAK2uDZfzyoLM5vW",
      "channelname": "TD Kolam",
      "imageURL": ""
    },
    {
      "playlistname": "?????",
      "playlistid": "PL7PWXzhNZZ0QRVUHZkouHO-Z6ONhPlejT",
      "channelname": "Sumathy G",
      "imageURL": ""
    },
    {
      "playlistname": "?????",
      "playlistid": "PLajt0f8unQ6XqkA_y41ypby_0_9lTf6s_",
      "channelname": "Selvamani Jayabal",
      "imageURL": ""
    },
    {
      "playlistname": "???????????? ???????",
      "playlistid": "PL_wM35e-Czjnzsa-97-IFOmEhOWIrJn1C",
      "channelname": "A to Z Nandhini",
      "imageURL": ""
    },
    {
      "playlistname": "Chikku kolangal",
      "playlistid": "PLSll0nWLklOE9i26_A8-wMHYM91ls-j_p",
      "channelname": "Dr.B.Selvamuthu Krishnan",
      "imageURL": ""
    },
    {
      "playlistname": "Pink",
      "playlistid": "PL-u817lYZC9GXncSo4pnnOp6EG0L-cuCk",
      "channelname": "jagan sekar",
      "imageURL": ""
    },
    {
      "playlistname": "Sk",
      "playlistid": "PLa7cnEZgdw5SH7ZMZENjF650Vv8CDY93L",
      "channelname": "Suresh Kalai",
      "imageURL": ""
    },
    {
      "playlistname": "Popular Videos - Kolam & Puja",
      "playlistid": "PL_ZkVSTePDMvkw9c6CLMCqxc7GlqD3EDU",
      "channelname": "Kolam - Topic",
      "imageURL": ""
    },
    {
      "playlistname": "Rangoli Design-Kolam Design",
      "playlistid": "PLFpOXrFtpgWhqGOQad3PdRZ-QUrBkOZ8l",
      "channelname": "Nagu's Handwork",
      "imageURL": ""
    },
    {
      "playlistname": "Kolam",
      "playlistid": "PLhSkx3hNgucQiXYpgrIZzcBSrBVr7Rr0D",
      "channelname": "Jamuna Rani",
      "imageURL": ""
    },
    {
      "playlistname": "Kambi kolam",
      "playlistid": "PLybpr3Tk6SmVFQ7QolQ2Pt45KbTu9IQKp",
      "channelname": "Balasubramanian Krishnamurthy",
      "imageURL": ""
    },
    {
      "playlistname": "Rangoli borders. kolam border. muggulu border",
      "playlistid": "PLBYk4p11EVupclfP6C4RbjHBu-9ylr1q9",
      "channelname": "TD Kolam",
      "imageURL": ""
    },
    {
      "playlistname": "CHIKKU KOLAM",
      "playlistid": "PLfvmbqiPYkkpuLW8psUOVz-kLCRu2EZcE",
      "channelname": "thilagalakshmi sridharan",
      "imageURL": ""
    },
    {
      "playlistname": "Popular Rangoli & Kolam videos",
      "playlistid": "PLxE-NIHKNadzvjuVu_EoKHHDbvunPzmJ2",
      "channelname": "Rangoli - Topic",
      "imageURL": ""
    },
    {
      "playlistname": "Popular Videos - Rangoli & Peafowl",
      "playlistid": "PLxE-NIHKNadxA5IAylBprcVUPYJNHaPaK",
      "channelname": "Rangoli - Topic",
      "imageURL": ""
    },
    {
      "playlistname": "Popular Thai Pongal & Kolam videos",
      "playlistid": "PLcIFZKKK5Ex29vy7lbWKbFstgoeG1XNCP",
      "channelname": "Thai Pongal - Topic",
      "imageURL": ""
    },
    {
      "playlistname": "aanmeegam / ????????",
      "playlistid": "PLCR_lidRFmjCnNhVRCRTENHZ360ySzTHH",
      "channelname": "Zio Tamil",
      "imageURL": ""
    },
    {
      "playlistname": "kolangal",
      "playlistid": "PL3CPcT90G7vPDD5Iw1A5FLNEMA_RXSoHY",
      "channelname": "LEARNGOODALL",
      "imageURL": ""
    },
    {
      "playlistname": "108 simple Diwali kolam designs ( 4 to 9 dots ) | an easy rangoli a day to learn for Diwali decoration ideas | simple New Year rangoli",
      "playlistid": "PLwHuVZQFx6IhZ-8HtC5umsnyNxFGGwfXt",
      "channelname": "Sudha Balaji",
      "imageURL": ""
    }
  ],
  "success": true
}
```

Any one kindly help to solve this error. 
Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON Parsing using PHP returns unicode/ascii character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860090/json-parsing-using-php-returns-unicode-ascii-character)

Comment: Can you help me more ??

Comment: Check charset in connection to database and database charset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check charset in connection: ( preferred to placed it in connection.php )

   ```
   header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
   include('connection.php');

   // Change character set to utf8
   mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");

   $query = "SELECT * FROM DevotionalCollection";
   $fetch=mysqli_query($con, $query ) or die(mysqli_error($con));

   if (mysqli_num_rows($fetch) > 0) {
       $response["data"] = array();
       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch)) {

           $data = array();
           $data["playlistname"] = $row["playlistname"];
           $data["playlistid"] = $row["playlistid"];
           $data["channelname"] = $row["channelname"];
           $data["imageURL"] = $row["imageURL"];

           //$response["data"] = array();
           array_push($response["data"], $data);

       }
       header('Content-type: text/json');
       $response["success"] = TRUE;
       // echoing JSON response
       echo json_encode($response);
   }else {
       // no products found
       $response["success"] = FALSE;
       $response["message"] = "No data found";

       // echo no users JSON
       echo json_encode($response);
   }

   ?>
   ```
2. Change charset in database:

   ALTER DATABASE DBNAME CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

Comment: Awesome! Have a nice coding!