# Reading JSON from remote URL in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have this JSON file:

http://www.jeewanaryal.com/angryQuiz/eighties/json/eighties.json

and I am trying to decode it in PHP as follows:

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://www.jeewanaryal.com/angryQuiz/eighties/json/eighties.json'); 
$data = json_decode($json);
var_dump($data);
```

But, the output I am getting is NULL. Am I missing anything?

Comment: from $data, the o/p is NULL

Comment: How can I output my whole json data?

Comment: Does your first line work, what does `var_dump($json);` give you?

Comment: I am now just trying those 3 lines of code only, I mean I am not looping through the JSON data. Only those 3 PHP lines and I get NULL :-(

Comment: (Windows Notepad issue) Please, consult this, I shared the problem too and it fixed it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290849/how-to-remove-multiple-utf-8-bom-sequences-before-doctype

Answer (score 8):

Using example from [PHP.NET json_last_error()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) I found that your json syntax is not correct:

```
switch (json_last_error()) {
        case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
            echo ' - No errors';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
            echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
            echo ' - Underflow or the modes mismatch';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
            echo ' - Unexpected control character found';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
            echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
            echo ' - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded';
        break;
        default:
            echo ' - Unknown error';
        break;
}
```

Output:

```
 - Syntax error, malformed JSON
```

However, I checked your json code in the following website but it says valid:

- http://www.freeformatter.com/json-validator.html
- http://jsonlint.com/
- http://json.parser.online.fr/
- http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Yes, I you are right. I used a new line break \n in my JSON file, that might be causing the problem. However, online JSON validation is good, its not a valid for PHP decoder.

Answer (score 5):

**Documentation**

`json_decode` can return `NULL` as the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) states.

> Returns the value encoded in json in appropriate PHP type. Values
>   true, false and null (case-insensitive) are returned as TRUE, FALSE
>   and NULL respectively. NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded
>   or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit.

**Your Problem**

`json_decode` is failing here because of `\n` inside of **id 6**

> { "id": 6, "url":
>   "http://jeewanaryal.com/angryQuiz/eighties/images/betterOffDead.jpg",
>   "question": "In the movie 'Better Off Dead', what was the \n name of
>   Lane's younger brother?", "answer": [ { "a": { "text": "Bradger",
>   "status": 1 } }, { "b": { "text": "Peter", "status": 0 } }, { "c": {
>   "text": "Frank", "status": 0 } }, { "d": { "text": "Michael",
>   "status": 0 } } ] }

**Solution**

I guess your best bet here is to escape them before `json_decode`

`$safe_json = str_replace("\n", "\\n", $json);`

Comment: But I don't know why am I getting NULL, this is a valid JSON.

Comment: wow, great catch, thanks. But I am just wondering its a valid JSON. I used \n to get a new line. Shouldn't it be supposed to work?

Comment: Escape them? I've added that to the answer.

Comment: Hey Rawkode, I tried the different JSON which does not have any new line character. I tried this one http://jeewanaryal.com/phpTest/jsonTest.json and still says NULL :-(. Looks like \n is not the problem here.

Comment: Nope, that decodes fine for me. Remove your `\n` and you'll see it works. If it's still `NULL` for you, then please check your php.ini as suggested by @jeroen

Comment: Ok thank you. I will check that.

Answer (score 0):

Please set the second parameter to true. This will give you an associative array. If the result is still null I'd be interested whether the file_get_contents returned something.

Comment: I tried yours, still NULL :-(

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but as you do not show what `$json` contains, I am going to assume that `file_get_contents` returned `false`, leading to the result you get.

You should check your `php.ini` file, what is the value for `allow_url_fopen`? If that is `0` that means that you cannot read a file from an `http` address so that could be the problem.

Just change the value of `allow_url_fopen` to `1` if that is the problem.