# json and PHP parse

Tags: php, json, parsing

Why i can't get out the values from the json file with PHP?
I get zero values? Have tried for hours.

```
    <?php


$json_string = 'http://pubapi.cryptsy.com/api.php?method=singlemarketdata&marketid=44';

$jsondata = file_get_contents($json_string);

$data = json_decode($jsondata, TRUE);

print_r($data);

echo "<br><br><br><br>";

foreach ($data as $recenttrades) {
    echo "VALUES('{$recenttrades->quantity}', '{$recenttrades->price}' ";
}


?>
```

Update: but can't get the value from primaryname and primarycode.

I have tried this:

```
$json_string = 'http://pubapi.cryptsy.com/api.php?method=marketdatav2';

$jsondata = file_get_contents($json_string);

$data = json_decode($jsondata, TRUE);

//print_r($data);


foreach ($data["market"] as $markets) { 
echo "Primary code: <strong>{$markets['primarycode']}</strong><br>";

  foreach($markets as $market) {
    foreach($market as $attributes) {
      foreach($attributes["recenttrades"] as $recenttrade) {

        echo "quantity: " . $recenttrade['quantity'] .", price: " . $recenttrade['price'] . "<br>";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but if 2nd argument = true, you get an associative array. But there you're trying to access the values from an object

Comment: Maybe this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15552385/reading-json-from-remote-url-in-php

Comment: Remove TRUE if you want an object to be returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others have mentioned that you're dealing with nested arrays, not objects.  Along with pointing out the issue of being nested rather deeply, I would suggest digging down with `foreach` (I will probably be crucified for this):

```
     <?php


$json_string = 'http://pubapi.cryptsy.com/api.php?method=singlemarketdata&marketid=44';

$jsondata = file_get_contents($json_string);

$data = json_decode($jsondata, TRUE);

//print_r($data);

echo "<br><br><br><br>";

foreach ($data as $markets) {
  foreach($markets as $market) {
    foreach($market as $attributes) {
      foreach($attributes["recenttrades"] as $recenttrade) { 
        //echo "<pre>";
        //print_r($recenttrade);
        //echo "</pre>";
        echo "VALUES('{quantity: " . $recenttrade['quantity'] ."}', 'price: {" . $recenttrade['price'] . "}')";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

?>

This will ensure that you grab every `recentrades` item at this level of the array.  This way   you are prepared for other markets to be added to the API and your code isn't locked into searching only in the item named "FST".

Comment: i like this. But how can i get other in the loop i have tried this:

Comment: You can copy that `echo` / `print_r` block that I'm doing on `$recenttrade` and apply it to each level of the `foreach` sequence. That will show you every `$key => $val` pair available on the given level. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

`recenttrades` is nested pretty deeply in that array.  Try

```
foreach ($data['return']['markets']['FST']['recenttrades'] as $recenttrades) {
```

Answer (score 2):

`recenttrades` is several levels nested, so simply doing `foreach($data as $recenttrades)` is not sufficient.

You need to do:

```
$recentTrades = $data['return']['markets']['FST']['recenttrades'];

foreach($recentTrades as $recentTrade) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`recenttrades` is nested deeply and you're asking for arrays, not objects.  This seems to work:

```
foreach ($data['return']['markets']['FST']['recenttrades'] as $recenttrades) {
    echo "VALUES('{$recenttrades['quantity']}', '{$recenttrades['price']}' ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In response to your update, where you want to loop over markets, try this:

```
foreach ($data['return']['markets'] as $market) {
  echo "Primary code: <strong>{$market['primarycode']}</strong><br>";
  foreach ($market["recenttrades"] as $recenttrade) {
      echo "quantity: " . $recenttrade['quantity'] .", price: " . $recenttrade['price'] . "<br>";
  }
}
```