# Incorrect parsing of variable string into GET query string

Tags: php, string, parsing, get, query-string

code:

```
function updateGUI()
    {
        foreach ($GLOBALS['content_array'] as $i)
        {
            $title = $i[0];
            $rating = $i[1];
            echo "<li class=contentList><a class=contentListLink href=filmer_php.php?title=".$title."><span class=spantitle>".$title."</span><span class=spanrating>".asteriskifyRating($rating)."</span></a></li>";
        }
    }
```

output:
[image]
[image]

resources:
http://dist3.webbintro.se/assignments/3/movies.txt

context: So I'm creating `<li>` with `<a>` attached to them and I'm getting the `$title` of the `<li>` from a global variable (not important).
The problem is that the query string doesn't contain the full string as some `$title` contain spaces, so they get cut off at the spaces. I've tried using escape characters `\"` but didn't work and I can't find any good article about how to properly parse..
Also I would prefer if the solution didn't include regex, but if this can only be solved with regex then so be it.

**EDIT1:**
context: Ok, urlencode fixed the biggest issue. I'm still getting a mojibake square before "Star Wars", any suggestion on what's causing this?

full code:
http://jsfiddle.net/Uv5bV/

**EDIT2:**
removed the utf-8 BOM, got the solution from this thread: [How to remove multiple UTF-8 BOM sequences before "<!DOCTYPE>"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290849/how-to-remove-multiple-utf-8-bom-sequences-before-doctype)

code:

```
function remove_utf8_bom($text)
    {
    $bom = pack('H*','EFBBBF');
    $text = preg_replace("/^$bom/", '', $text);
    return $text;
    }
```

Comment: You might want to check the HTML you're generating. You need to put quotes around the links - at the moment, it's effectively `<a href=filmer_php.php?title=Star Wars>`, and anything after the space is being treated as a separate attribute of the tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add [url encoding](http://php.net/manual/it/function.urlencode.php):

```
echo '<li class="contentList"><a class="contentListLink" href="filmer_php.php?title='.urlencode($title).'"><span class="spantitle">'.$title.'</span><span class="spanrating">'.asteriskifyRating($rating).'</span></a></li>';
```

You should also pay more attention to quotes (single and double).

Comment: Worked, thanks. Not sure why I didn't search the php reference for this..
The mojibake square before "Star Wars" persists though, do you know how I can remove it?

Comment: For that you have to check your data before the cycle.. it seems that the weird character it's already present before, because the cycle code looks fine.

Comment: Ok, I've added the code to the question (check the jsfiddle).
I removed Star Wars from the textfile and loaded in the 3 entries after that, the mojibake appears before Fight Club now so it seems to be something with the reading process.