# How to convert terminal output to HTML file format

Tags: html, output, aix, ansi-escape

I was using "ansi2html.sh"  here http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/ansi2html.sh to get my job done.

```
ls -lrt /web/htdocs | tail -12 | ./ansi2html.sh --bg=dark >test.html
```

I was using ansible on local host having Linux OS to run this across multiple hosts which generated the html files on each of the remote hosts and then i would finally pull all the html files from all remote to my local ansible server.

This worked fine for all Linux systems.

However, "ansi2html.sh" has dependency of `gawk` which is not present on a set of production AiX 6.1 and 7 system.

I get this error:

```
./ansi2html.sh[38]: gawk:  not found
```

As my AiX is hosting the production application; installing `gawk` is not recommended.

I dont know if the solution could be to get the output of `ls -lrt` from all AiX host and then feed that output to "ansi2html.sh" on the local ansible linux server having `gawk`. Not sure if this will work and if so how ? Note: i wish the output to have the same look and feel as on the putty terminal prompt.

Can I get a solution for AiX so i could use ansible to get html files with the output of `ls -lrt` from across all AiX hosts ?

Comment: In your Linux box: `ssh user@aixhost 'ls -lrt /web/htdocs | tail -12' | ./ansi2html.sh --bg=dark >test.html`

Comment: This solution works. However I will post another question to make this solution work using Ansible. Can you please put this as an answer @Lorinczy Zsigmond

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Already written as comment) You can use `ssh` to execute a command on the remote computer and process the output on the local computer. Example:

```
ssh user@aixhost 'ls -lrt /web/htdocs | tail -12' |
./ansi2html.sh --bg=dark >test.html
```

Standard input can be redirected, too, e.g:

```
ssh user1@host1 'cd frompath; tar -czf - sendme/' |
ssh user2@host2 'cd topath; tar -xzf -'
```

Note: I know nothing about Ansible, but I heard that with it you can do almost everything you could do without it.

Answer (score 2):

Using [aha](https://github.com/theZiz/aha) *Ansi HTML Adapter*  for this task, works very well:

```
ls -lrt ~ | tail -12 | aha --black --title "Home list"> ls.html
```

Example using `html2text`

```
curl https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60465150/how-to-convert-terminal-output-to-html-file-format | html2text | aha --black --title "the SO question"> txt.html
```

Install:

```
sudo apt install aha
sudo apt install html2text
```

---

This is possible to convert ANSII encoding using `iconv`:
[Force encode from US-ASCII to UTF-8 (iconv)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303405/force-encode-from-us-ascii-to-utf-8-iconv)

---

Lastly, all that is also doable from **php** alone, which should works everywhere. Quick base to convert html to text using php:

```
php -r 'echo htmlspecialchars(trim(strip_tags("<div> <b>Hello</b> world</div>")));'
// Hello world
```

---

ANSII to text from **php** using REGEXes:

```
$ansii = " |[0m [34m▓▓▓▓▓[0m";
echo preg_replace("/\x1B\[[0-9;]*[JKmsu]/","",$ansii);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59060531/2494754

Comment: Installation is discouraged on AiX as mentioned in the original post. I can grab the output from AiX to Linux and then process it if that will work as a solution? Please suggest.

Comment: Ok, then it won't be easy. This is doable using only php. Added a base example.