# PHP - json_decode from mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I have an Android app, PHP page and MySql db.
The android app send a string parameter to the server, I use Gson so I know that the Json string is correct.
On server side I store that string of json as `Text` field.
On web client I take that field from my database and doing json_decode and receives a `NULL`.
Most of the site written by `PHPMAKER 10` so I use it's database connection.

```
$result="";
$rs->MoveFirst();
if ($rs) {
    $result = $rs->fields[0];
}
$rs->Close();
$extras = json_decode($result, true);
```

I checked that json in [Json validator](http://jsonlint.com/) and it looks fine.

Any ideas why I gets null? (maybe encoding)

**EDIT:**
I did the following check:

```
echo "<script> var x = {$result}; console.log(x.length)</script>";
```

Chrome gave the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

**EDIT 2:**
If I print that string `echo $result` and copy that to a variable it works.

Comment: What's the result of `var_export($result)`?

Comment: A string, I checked it with var_dump.

Comment: The [`json_last_error_msg`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php) function will give you to the error message.

Comment: The error is just number 4 (JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX), but I already checked the json.

Comment: Is the JSON string too long to check by hand? Start removing bits, or start by adding bits to `{}`, see which part the parser doesn't like.

Comment: The json is 644 characters according to var dump

Comment: I did some more checks, see the edit.

Comment: What is the result of `substr($result, 0, 3);`? Or did you already check the encoding?

Comment: substr($result, 0, 3) => {"d

Comment: Seems to be okay. Can you post the whole JSON?

Comment: Try to convert it to UTF-8 using iconv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I soled the problem:
My json contained breaklines `'/r' and '/r/n'`.
After removing them everything was fine.

Answer (score 3):

That happened to me, when there was a UTF-8 BOM at the beginning of the JSON string. JSON is UTF-8 as default, so that BOM seems to be forbidden.

You could use this function to remove it:

```
//Remove UTF8 Bom

function remove_utf8_bom($text)
{
    $bom = pack('H*','EFBBBF');
    $text = preg_replace("/^$bom/", '', $text);
    return $text;
}
```

Taken from here: [How to remove multiple UTF-8 BOM sequences before "<!DOCTYPE>"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290849/how-to-remove-multiple-utf-8-bom-sequences-before-doctype)