# Deserialize entity with JSON fail in Symfony

Tags: php, json, symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I'm trying to deserialize an entity from a JSON file with this method

```
public function importAnnotationAction($id_rendu)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $jsonContent = $this->get("request")->getContent();

    $serializer = $this->get('serializer');
    $annotationEntity = $serializer->deserialize($jsonContent, 'Alecsia\AnnotationBundle\Entity\Annotation', 'json');

    //Save entity
    $em->persist($annotationEntity);
    $em->flush();

    return new Response($jsonContent . "\n" . var_dump($annotationEntity));
}
```

the JSON file used is from a same entity

and the output entity fields are all set to null :

> object(Alecsia\AnnotationBundle\Entity\Annotation)#568 (18) {
>   ["id":protected]=> int(26) ["fichier":protected]=> NULL
>   ["rendu":protected]=> NULL ["modele":protected]=> NULL
>   ["debut_ligne":protected]=> int(0) ["debut_col":protected]=> int(0)
>   ["fin_ligne":protected]=> int(0) ["fin_col":protected]=> int(0)
>   ["nom":protected]=> NULL ["commentaire":protected]=> NULL
>   ["valeur":protected]=> NULL ["relatif":protected]=> NULL
>   ["exercice":protected]=> NULL ["deleguer_nom":protected]=> bool(false)
>   ["deleguer_commentaire":protected]=> bool(false)
>   ["deleguer_valeur":protected]=> bool(false)
>   ["deleguer_relatif":protected]=> bool(false)
>   ["deleguer_exercice":protected]=> bool(false) }

and the entity id increment with each call, what am I doind wrong?

Comment: Can you paste the request body?

Comment: @PeterBailey the JSON data ?

Comment: Yes. I'm curious about what is actually ending up in `$jsonContent`

Comment: @PeterBailey here is the json content : http://pastebin.com/sV0W53E3

Comment: Ok, so is this a POST request then? Have you 100% verified that `$jsonContent` has that content?  What about your `Annotation` entity - does it have a public setter for each of those properties?

Comment: @PeterBailey for the jsonContent it's from the var dump, and I think there is a setter for every fields, but some fields name use underscore and setter use CamelCase

Comment: The underscore vs camelCase issue could be a problem, but I don't know the nuts and bolts of how that serializer bundle works i.e., what type of field-name conversions it attempts it order to match a target property/setter on the outbound object.

Comment: @PeterBailey I try something new : import another entity, and the bundle told me that there was missing annotation (@Type) So I set them all in every entity file. But then I have an error : `Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, integer given` for the other entity and the Annotation export still failed

Comment: @PeterBailey But does every protected field need to have its own setter? If so I'll try and look if there is any one missing

Comment: If there is a issue with underscore and CamelCase you can use `use JMS/Serializer/Annotation as Serializer` and then above `setSomeKindOfField()` add the annotation `@Serializer\SerializedName('some_kind_of_field')`. Alternatively you could add it to you YAML if you go swing that way.

Comment: (Windows Notepad issue) Please, consult this, I shared the problem too and it fixed it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290849/how-to-remove-multiple-utf-8-bom-sequences-before-doctype