# CSV upload - parsing with SplFileObject - Remove BOM

Tags: php, csv, byte-order-mark

I have a form to upload a `CSV` file:

```
<form method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <p><input type="file" name="file" /></p>
  <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

On my PHP script I do the following:

```
$temp = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

$fobject = new SplFileObject($temp);
$fobject->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);
$fobject->setCsvControl(',', '"');

$data = [];
foreach($fobject as $line) {
$data[] = $line;
  print_r($line);
}
```

Now there is a `BOM` in the file which shows as a

> ï»¿

in the first `CSV` row. How can I remove this?

I Googled and tried some solutions ([How to remove multiple UTF-8 BOM sequences before "<!DOCTYPE>"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290849/how-to-remove-multiple-utf-8-bom-sequences-before-doctype)) but did not work.

I can use `str_replace`, but this does not seem like a best practice to me.

Comment: Is the first row a header row?

Comment: No, there is no header row.

Comment: if you temporarily remove the accept-charset="utf-8" in the html tag, do you get that problem? Does your html doctype tag contain any attributes? Did you see this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290849/how-to-remove-multiple-utf-8-bom-sequences-before-doctype?lq=1

Comment: This link is actually what I tried and did not work. But now I found out that I have to call the function before doing utf8_decode. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Original post taken from here: [chrisguitarguy/no_bom.php](https://gist.github.com/chrisguitarguy/6096271)

```
<?php
$file = new \SplFileObject('some_file_with_bom.csv');
// http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8
$bom = pack('CCC', 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF);
$first = true;
foreach ($file as $line) {
    if ($first && substr($line, 0, 3) === $bom) {
        $line = substr($line, 3);
    }

    $first = false;

    // your lines don't have a BOM, do your stuff
}
```

Worked for me !