# json_decode from https url JSON validation on https

Tags: php, json, validation, https

Can anyone shed any light on why

```
http://jsonlint.com/
```

and

```
http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/
```

is giving invalid json from URL 1 below but not URL 2? They are both the same JSON generating code. The only difference is one is HTTPs and one is HTTP.

```
https://www.discussthemarket.com/dev/
JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

and also

```
http://www.lambwatch.co.uk/json.htm
Valid JSON
```

Both have the same JSON generating code behind them, exact same code, but when I put the URLs into

```
http://jsonlint.com/
```

for validation, the https site is coming back with a parse error!?

Also, when I do

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.discussthemarket.com/dev/"));
$json is  NULL
```

However

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.lambwatch.co.uk/json.htm"));
$json is the object as you'd expect
```

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: Neither of those functions perform any network requests nor care where the data came from, so no.

Comment: Could you share that parse error with us?

Comment: Wait you're putting the URL's in to http://jsonlint.com/? This is a bug with the website then - I pasted the strings from both sites and they validate fine.

Comment: @Bulk yes, apparently you can put a URL in there for validation.

Comment: @DanielProcter you need to take it up with http://jsonlint.com/ then - we can't help you futher here, there is no code issue.

Comment: @Bulk, i've added some more info which would suggest it is something more, as trying to json_decode the two URLs results in different behaviour

Comment: Ah yeah this is a whole other thing then - this is a network issue trying to get data from a https site - this isn't related to the JSON at all.

Comment: @castis i've added the json error to the question. Here it is JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: @DanielProcter The issue is you're getting NO data from the https site, not invalid data. Try echoing the contents of just the `file_get_contents` with out passing it though `json_decode`. This is 100% not related to JSON in any way.

Comment: @Bulk - aye, tis weird. Any thoughts at all? I've compared server headers and they are the same except the https is 99 content length while the http is 96 characters long... Where's that extra stuff?! That is surely it

Comment: do a `var_dump()` on the results from both sites (with out passing it to any json_decode()) see what you get.

Comment: @Bulk - I've done a var dump and confirmed there's 3 more in length.. As  rjdown has confirmed below. looks like i have a rogue BOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the HTTPS server is adding a UTF8 BOM character to the start of the output, therefore invalidating the expected JSON response. Without seeing the code, it's unclear why, but it's likely a header issue.

If you're unable to solve it server-side, you can always simply remove it at the other end. [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15423899/1301076)

```
<?php

$response = file_get_contents('https://www.discussthemarket.com/dev/');
$json = remove_utf8_bom($response);
var_dump(json_decode($json));

function remove_utf8_bom($text) {
    $bom = pack('H*', 'EFBBBF');
    $text = preg_replace("/^$bom/", '', $text);
    return $text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks rjdown You've nailed it. I will do some digging and try and get rid of that BOM server side! Appreciate it! Will post back when i've fixed to confirm answer. Much appreciated.

Comment: Fixed. I had [no end of line] issues in the generating code. Sorted. Thank you!