# Parse JSON response in PHP - Protected keys?

Tags: php, json

I am using `Curl` to perform a GET request on a Sage server. The response is in JSON format, but I am unable to access the key/values.

An example of the response is below:

```
{
"$descriptor": "Sage Accounts 50 | tradingAccount.",
  "$totalResults": 1508,
  "$startIndex": 1,
  "$itemsPerPage": 1508,
  "$resources": [
   {
      "$url": "http://it1:5493/sdata/accounts50/GCRM/{53C58AA8-1677-46CE-BCBE-4F07FED3668F}/tradingAccountCustomer(9a7a0179-85cb-4b65-9d02-73387073ac83)?format=atomentry",
      "$uuid": "9a7a0179-85cb-4b65-9d02-73387073ac83",
      "$httpStatus": "OK",
      "$descriptor": "",
      "active": true,
      "customerSupplierFlag": "Customer",
      "companyPersonFlag": "Company",
      "invoiceTradingAccount": null,
      "openedDate": "\/Date(1246834800000+0100)\/",
      "reference": "1STCL001",
      "reference2": null,
      "status": "Open"
    }
    /* Additional results omitted for simplicity */
}
```

I need to access 2 key/value pairs for each child of `$resources`. The first is `$uuid` and the second is `reference`.

I have attempted various methods including:

```
$result=curl_exec($ch);
$resources = $result->{'$resources'};
print_r($resources); /* Non-object error */
```

Can someone shed some light on how I can access these key/values, please?

## Update

If I perform the following action, I receive a `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object` error.

```
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
$resources = $result->{'$resources'};
print_r($resources);
```

## Edit 2

Entire code currently used:

```
<?php 
header('content-type:application/json');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$url = "http://it1:5493/sdata/accounts50/GCRM/-/tradingAccounts?format=json";

$header = array();
$header[] = 'Authorization: Basic bWFuYWdlcjpjYmwyMDA4';
$header[] = 'Content-Type: application/json;';

//  Initiate curl
$ch = curl_init();
// Will return the response, if false it print the response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// Set the url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
// Set the header
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
// Execute
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));

if ($result === false)
{
    // throw new Exception('Curl error: ' . curl_error($crl));
    print_r('Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch));
}
// Closing
curl_close($ch);

// Access property $resources
$resources = $result->{'$resources'};

// Dump results
print_r($resources);


?>
```

## Edit 3

Output of `var_dump($result);`

```
string '{
   "$descriptor": "Sage Accounts 50 | tradingAccount",
   "$totalResults": 1508,
   "$startIndex": 1,
   "$itemsPerPage": 1508,
   "$resources": [
      {
       "$url": "http://it1:5493/sdata/accounts50/GCRM/{53C58AA8-1677-46CE-BCBE-4F07FED3668F}/tradingAccountCustomer(9a7a0179-85cb-4b65-9d02-73387073ac83)?format=atomentry",
       "$uuid": "9a7a0179-85cb-4b65-9d02-73387073ac83",
       "$httpStatus": "OK",
       "$descriptor": "",
       '... (length=5333303)
```

Comment: $resources is an array, not an object, because it starts with `[`

Comment: What errors do you get? Did you set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` in the `$ch` handle?

Comment: @Peter It does not have anything to do with that. The problem is that `curl_exec` does not parse JSON,

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen please see my edit

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen you're right, he must use json_decode

Comment: @MikeF `var_dump($result);` and post result

Comment: What prevents you from issuing a `var_dump()` over `$result`?

Comment: `curl_exec` returns `true` or `false` by default. If you set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` then it *may* return an object, but it may also return `false`. You should check what `curl_exec` returns before doing anything with it. That is your problem.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen - please see my latest edits which have the full script and also the `var_dump($result);` output

Comment: @MikeF we need the dump after using `json_decode(curl_exec($ch))`

Comment: @Peter the output of `var_dump(json_decode(curl_exec($ch)));` is `null`

Comment: @MikeF then it seems that the Sage response is not a valid json string. Use this online parser to check if the string is a valid json string [JSON Parser](http://json.parser.online.fr/)

Comment: @Peter I've just copied the json response to jsonlint.com and it's saying it is valid JSON

Comment: @MikeF could you post the entire json? Maybe it's a recursion depth problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:
The server response was UTF-8 encoded with BOM (byte-order-mark) which caused the `json_encode` to fail with `JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX`

working code

```
$string = curl_exec($ch);

$object = json_decode(remove_utf8_bom($string),true);


foreach ($object as $key => $value)
    if (is_array($value))
        foreach($value as $k=>$arr){
            print $arr['$uuid'] . PHP_EOL;
            print $arr['reference'] . PHP_EOL;
        }

function remove_utf8_bom($text)
{
    $bom = pack('H*','EFBBBF');
    $text = preg_replace("/^$bom/", '', $text);
    return $text;
}
```

`remove_utf8_bom` function ripped from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/15423899/5043552

---

This is how you can access the key/values, assuming `$result` is the contents of `json_decode` as per your latest edit.

```
foreach ($result->{'$resources'} as $obj){
    print $obj->{'$uuid'} . PHP_EOL;
    print $obj->reference . PHP_EOL;
}
// prints out
// 9a7a0179-85cb-4b65-9d02-73387073ac83
// 1STCL001
```

Answer (score 2):

The server is returning the JSON encoded as UTF-8 with BOM which puts 3 characters at the begining of the string. Just try to obtain the JSON correctly encoded or if you can't, remove the 3 first characters and then use `json_decode` to obtain the PHP object.

Comment: Thanks Peter. After further investigation it was found that the Sage server was indeed returning with UTF-8 with BOM encoding. A quick `substr($result,3)` resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing json_decode call. Try this:

```
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
$resources = $result->{'$resources'};
```

Comment: This returns the following error: `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\sage-test.php on line <i>32</i>`. Which relates to `$resources = $result->{'$resources'};`

Comment: Double check what you're getting from the remote server. Just echo whatever curl_exec is returning.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch)); // Decode the JSON
$resources = $result->{'$resources'}; // Access the $resources property which is an array
print_r($resources); // Prints an array
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
$resources = $result->{'$resources'};
```

You have to decode JSON

Answer (score 0):

The key fact here that everyone else seems to be missing is that `$resources` is an defined in the JSON as array, not an object, so `json_decode()` will turn it into a PHP array, not a PHP object.

```
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
$resources = $result['$resources'];   //resources is an array, not an object.

foreach ($resources as $resource) {
    //but each resource is an object...
    print $resource->{'$url}."\n";
    print $resource->{'$uuid}."\n";
    // ...etc...
}
```

Comment: I am now receiving a `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ` error

Comment: Add a `var_dump` or `print_r` before the `foreach()` to see what's going on.

Comment: On the bright side, at least the code got past the `$resource = $result['$resources']` line, so that much seems to have worked. And that was the main point of my answer.