# Removing an extra space from a table content

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I am importing a CSV file which contains list of URLS. These URLs are displaying in tabular format to perform some operations. But a space is added to the beginning of url. Because of this the operations I am performing on it fails. So how I can remove that space.When I done print_r() in my controller it shows result as
�https://www.surveygizmo.com

```
if (($handle = fopen($filename, "r")) !== FALSE) 
{
    while (($value = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
    {
         $num = count($value);

         for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) 
         {
               echo "<pre>";
               print_r($value[$c]);
```

Above a few lines of code. I am getting symbol,� before the content.

How can I remove that? I tried with trim. But still its not working. I need help. Thank you

Comment: what u have tried so far ,pls put some code there

Comment: I think that's UTF-8 BOM. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15423899/9618184).

Comment: Thank you Binar Web for your support for beginners like me. The page which you linked helped me to resolve it. The final url after using that function gave '?' instead of space and then I trimmed '?'. Finally got the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I have similar issue and after following tweak it fixed

```
$col_val = $value[$c];
$final_value = trim($col_val ," \t\n\r\0\x0B\"");
print_r($final_value);
```