# php see and remove broken symbols from string

Tags: php

based on [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290849/how-to-remove-multiple-utf-8-bom-sequences-before-doctype) question.

I am parsing a file with bom and get some strange content that I need to remove (see image below)

[image: garbage content]

I am trying to remove bom, but apparently this is not bom as solutions with bom removing are not working. Also I tried this:

```
$str = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x7F-\x9F]/u', '', trim($str));
$str = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F\xA0]/u', '', trim($str));
```

So I need to see what this actually is and remove it. This occurs only with the 1st line of file, all other lines do not contain it. Any ideas how to fix it would be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: So you only need A-z + underscores?

Comment: No, I need all valid letters, symbols, arithmetic signs etc, everything that could be correctly showed it chrome dev tools, but this uis actually a tricky issue. So I need to see what that actually is (that red dot) and to remove it.

Comment: is preg_replace('/\x{FEFF}/u', '', $text);  helpful ?

Comment: You should not look to remove it but to "kill" the source of it so it does not get added in the first place

Comment: Start with `var_dump bin2hex($first_line)`

Comment: Or `var_dump(array_map('dechex', array_map('ord', str_split($first_line))))` if you prefer

Comment: preg_replace('/\x{FEFF}/u', '', $text); was really helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can use this . and get

$str =  ".test_id_sbj";

$result= explode('.',$str);

echo $r  = $result[1];

Comment: It's a 3-character string with no unicode representation, not a `.`

Comment: It's not my code, but I can see that the image in the question says `string(14)`