# fgetcsv leaving quotes on first item

Tags: php, quotes, fgetcsv

I am having problems reading a CSV file where the values are encapsulated in quotes.

The first line of my CSV file are headers and they look like the following:

`"Header 1","Header 2","Header 3","Header 4","Header 5"`

When using fgetcsv, the first header retains the surrounding quotes.

```
while (($row = fgetcsv($file, 6000, ',')) !== false)
{
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($row);
    echo '</pre>';
    exit;
}
```

This outputs the following to the page

```
Array
(
    [0] => ﻿"Header 1"
    [1] => Header 2
    [2] => Header 3
    [3] => Header 4
    [4] => Header 5
)
```

Does anyone have any advice on how to make sure the quotes are not included in the first array item?

Thanks

Comment: `fgetcsv()` has an optional "enclosure" parameter. https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior with http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php, maybe try pulling in the 6000 records and then use the string function?

Comment: Does your file have a BOM? AFAIK, this is a known problem with UTF-8 BOMs, see [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php#122696). See also [this bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63433).

Answer (score 0):

As Karsten Koop as a comment stated, it's probably due to a utf8 BOM character. And since php is not solving this behaviour, you'll need to get rid of that char before opening the csv-file for reading.

i.e. using a function like this ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10290849/3710053)):

```
public static function removeUtf8Bom($fileUri){
    $content = file_get_contents($fileUri);
    $content = str_replace("\xEF\xBB\xBF",'',$content);
    file_put_contents($fileUri,$content);
}
```