# preg_replace UTF-8 BOM Unicode character

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8, byte-order-mark

I ran into the BOM Unicode character when parsing a CSV file and found this neat solution that solved the problem.

```
//Remove UTF8 Bom
function remove_utf8_bom($text) {
    $bom = pack('H*','EFBBBF');
    $text = preg_replace("/^$bom/", '', $text);
    return $text;
}
```

Link: [How to remove multiple UTF-8 BOM sequences before "<!DOCTYPE>"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290849/how-to-remove-multiple-utf-8-bom-sequences-before-doctype)

However, I don't completely understand how this works and was wondering if someone could explain what's happening here.

Some questions that I have:

1. Is 'EFBBBF' a HEX representation of the BOM Unicode character?
2. What is H*? (I assume this is how we specify the format of the 'EFBBBF' string)
3. Is it necessary to convert the 'EFBBBF' to a binary representation?
4. When I try to print the $bom variable, it's just an empty string. Why is the BOM invisible?
5. How does the preg_replace work with binary characters?

Answer (score 2):

The `BOM` is Unicode character `U+FEFF`.

`EFBBBF` is the hex representation of the UTF-8 encoding of this character. `pack('H*', ...)` takes a string and converts it into bytes assuming that each pair of characters in the string represent the byte value in hex.

Writing the `BOM` as the string `EFBBBF` makes it easier to type, but does mean you have to convert it to bytes, using `pack` in order to compare it to the `BOM` at the start of your data.

The `BOM` is invisible when you print it because `U+FEFF` is the Unicode character `ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE` it's only used as a `BOM` if it's the first character in the file.

In order for this to work correctly `$text` has to be the raw UTF-8 data stream. If it has been decoded from UTF-8 to characters then you can skip most of this and simply write

```
$text = preg_replace("/^\uFEFF/", '', $text);
```

Comment: thanks for the response. How do I determine if something is a raw UTF-8 data stream?

Comment: The above does not work without the pack() function.

Comment: @fsociety You need to know. see [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187169/how-to-detect-the-encoding-of-a-file#187174) question