# PHP does not properly output read file

Tags: php, iframe, embed

I've got a text file that contains a youtube url code for example: BzRBCM89GvI

I want this to be placed inside a iFrame and the title of the file to be used as a title above the video. I almost have it but for some reason the link does not appear to be working. If i inspect the element the URL LOOKS good but when i copy paste it to a text editor i get this: https://www.youtube.com/embed/%EF%BB%BFBzRBCM89GvI

The extra: "%EF%BB%BF" mess it up i think.

This is the PHP code:

```
<?PHP
$projects = glob('images/Projects/Video/*');

foreach ($projects as &$project) {  
    $src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" . file_get_contents($project);
    echo'<h3>' . str_replace(".txt","",str_replace("images/Projects/Video/","",$project)) . '</h3><iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" style="min-height: 300px; width: 100%;" type="text/html" src="' . $src . '"></iframe>';
}
?>
```

Any idea's why the extra bits are added or why it's not working?

Comment: How did you save the file?

Comment: I'm using Visual studio connected with the FTP off my webserver so just right click and new file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the [Byte Order Mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) of a UTF-8 encoded file.  Save the file without BOM.  Most text editors have this ability.

If you don't have control of the file and need to remove the BOM, check  [How to remove multiple UTF-8 BOM sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290849/how-to-remove-multiple-utf-8-bom-sequences-before-doctype)

Skipping the first 3 characters/bytes might also work, but this assumes that the BOM is always present:

```
substr(file_get_contents($project), 3);
```

Comment: Indeed! I found some code to remove the BOM and now it works! Thank you!