# PHP - After getting a csv file parsed into an array, can not match two exact strings

Tags: php, laravel, csv

I'm trying to parse a CSV file and read its contents. I get file like this:

```
$lines = file(base_path() . '/storage/data/test.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
```

After that, I use dd($lines) to get its output and it's like this:

```
array:4 [
  0 => "Column1,Column2,Column3"
  1 => "row11,row12,row13"
  2 => "row21,row22,row23"
  3 => "row31,row32,row33"
]
```

Which is okay so far. I'm exploding every line.

```
$check = 'Column1';
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $exploded = explode(',', $line);
    if (($index = array_search($check, $exploded)) !== false) {
        echo $index;
    }
}
```

I can get every index of that $exploded array for matching value. Except "Column1", A1 value. I've also checked that after the first explode function:

`dd(trim($exploded[0]) === trim($check))`

It's printing "false". But I've printed them both, and they are both "Column1". Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Use something to show the actual string length(something like `var_dump()`), it may be that there is a byte order mark (BOM) on the start of the file.

Comment: @NigelRen like you said, I've checked with var_dump. Length of $exploded[0] is 13 and length of $check is 10. I've trimmed $exploded[0] and still 13. What could have been the problem?

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290849/how-to-remove-multiple-utf-8-bom-sequences

Comment: FYI: I would change `base_path() . '/storage/data/test.csv'` into `base_path('storage/data/test.csv')` or even better: `storage_path('data/test.csv')`. It is not part of the issue, but please use functions as they are intended :D

Comment: @RobBiermann I've appreciated for your comment. I'll make those changes and keep them in mind for further :)